# Probability of limsup

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Let $A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots$ be a sequence of independent events on $\left (\Omega, \mathbb A, \mathbb P\right )$ such that $\mathbb P(A_n) < 1$ and $\mathbb P\left (\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\right ) = 1$.

Why is it valid that: $\mathbb P\left (\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup\limits _{n=m}^{\infty} A_n\right ) = 1$ ?

Comment: I think it would be sufficient to prove $P(\bigcup\limits_{n=m}^\infty A_n) = 1$ for any $m$. it seems to me this must be true, because none of the event happen with probability 1.

Comment: But, in fact, this is already the assumption, isn't it?

Comment: Or at least, it follows directly by the assumption.

Comment: enlighten me, how to prove this from the assumption?

Comment: because I am stuck this bit, I think if we know this, the rest is easy. let me write out something proper

Comment: By the [Borel-Cantelli lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel–Cantelli_lemma) and the second Borel-Cantelli lemma, the assertion is equivalent to proving that $\sum_{n\geq 1}P(A_n)=+\infty$.

Comment: @julien you can see the proof I posted below

Answer (score 9):

Since $A_1,A_2,...$ are independent it follows that $A_1^c,A_2^c...$ are independent. 
Therefore
$$P(\cup A_n)=1\Rightarrow$$
$$P(\cap A_n^c)=0\Rightarrow$$
$$\prod P(A_n^c)=0\Rightarrow $$
$$\prod (1-P(A_n))=0$$
Now, a theorem from Real Analysis which can be easily proved , states that:

> **Suppose $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^\infty\subset(0,1).  $ Then $$\prod(1-a_j)=0\iff \sum a_j=\infty $$**

Applying this to our case gives that $\sum P(A_n)=\infty$.$$$$
Now, the 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma states:

> **If  $\sum P(A_n)=\infty$ and the events $\{A_n\}$ are independent, then $$P(\limsup A_n)=1$$**

And this implies our desired result:$$P(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^\infty\bigcup\limits_{n=m}^\infty A_n)=P(\limsup A_n)=1$$

Comment: Nicely done, +1. What is exactly the definition of independence for an infinite set of events?

Comment: In Real Analysis, Folland the definition is : 
We define a collection $\{E_a\}_{a\in A}$ of events in $\Omega$ to be independent if $P(E_{a_1}\cap ... \cap E_{a_n})=\prod\limits_{1}^{n}P(E_{a_j})$ for all n and all distinct $a_i$.

Comment: However, generally $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n A_k)= P(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$. 
Indeed, let $B_n=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n A_k$. Then $\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty B_n$ , and $P(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty A_k)=P(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^\infty B_k)=\lim P(B_n) = \lim P(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^n A_k) $

Comment: Thank you very much for these precisions, that's indeed a natural definition. I wish this answer had more upvotes.

Comment: @julien agreed, so it wasn't kolmogorov... my mind is not in peace. though it doesnt look like OP cares much about it :P